# spreadsheets.values.batchUpdate() completes successfully, but the destination sheet is still empty

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

The script doesn't throw any errors, but rarely *completely* works - i.e. complete successfully with all of the expected data in the destination tab.  The results breakdown is generally:

1. no results in the destination sheet - this happens ~50-75% of the time
2. all of the results in the destination sheet, except in cell A1 - ~25% of the time
3. 100% completely works - ~15-25% of the time

code snippet of the batchupdate() call

```
var data = [
              {
                 range: (ss.getSheetName() + "!A1:AQ" + valueArray.length)
                ,values: valueArray
               }
             ];
  
  const resource = {
       valueInputOption: "RAW"
      ,data: data
   };
  
  
  Logger.log("request       = " + JSON.stringify(resource)
    + "\n" + "valueArray           = " + valueArray.length
  );
  
  
  Logger.log(" Sheets.Spreadsheets.Values.batchUpdate(params, batchUpdateValuesRequestBody)    ");
  var response = Sheets.Spreadsheets.Values.batchUpdate(resource, spreadsheetId);

  Logger.log("response  = " + response.toString());
```

and the response

```
response = {
    "totalUpdatedRows": 37776,
    "responses": [{
            "updatedCells": 1482389,
            "updatedRange": "BatchUpdateDestination!A1:AP37776",
            "updatedColumns": 42,
            "spreadsheetId": "adahsdassadasdsadaasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdas",
            "updatedRows": 37776
        }
    ],
    "spreadsheetId": "adahsdassadasdsadaasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdas",
    "totalUpdatedCells": 1482389,
    "totalUpdatedSheets": 1,
    "totalUpdatedColumns": 42
}
```

Its obviously a very large dataset, but I've pruned the destination spreadsheet to ensure there is ample room for the data, and from earlier testing, I believe that a specific size error would be returned if that was the blocker.

How can I troubleshoot, or better yet, prevent these incomplete executions?  is there any way to inspect the batch jobs that these requests initiate?

Comment: How can we help?

Comment: What is the question? If you need help to debug your code add a [mcve].

Comment: sorry for leaving out the actual question!  updated now, and tia.

Comment: @swv - we would need to see your code for this - please, include it in the question. Your data structure is not particularly important if we cannot see *how* are you trying to call `batchUpdate()`.

Comment: The issue might be caused by surpassing [Apps Script quota](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas), [SheetsAPI limits](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/limits) and your specific case very likely from the general [Drive limitations](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/37603?hl=en), for example if your spreadsheet surpasses 5 000 000 cells / 18,278 columns. Check the size of the spreadsheet. Also, test your request with [Try this API](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/batchUpdate) to exclude the Apps Script quota

Comment: @OlegValter - i've added a snippet of the code that makes the API call.

Comment: @ziganotschka - i'm not sure if size limits is an issue, since as I mentioned, the code seems to work as expected some of the times and I've verified that this additional data (1482389 cells) will not cause the total cells or columns count to exceed the 5M max.  That said, I'd certainly love to test without any quota, but I'm not sure how to configure that option.  The current script doesn't show in the the dropdown list of available projects in the sheets API dashbaord?

Comment: @swv - thank you for updating the question. I think you should add more info, up to `valueArray` and `ss` delclaration. Also: what's the length of `valueArray`?

Comment: You can not check you Apps Script quota, you can only try to test the request without Apps Script, that is writing an App in another language or with the `Try this API` (admittedly the latter would be a bit hard for over a million of cells). Mind that if `ss` is defined as a spreadsheet and not sheet, this  might lead to errors.

Answer (score 1):

Answering my own question...

After toiling with this a little more, I couldn't figure out any way to troublshooting or inspect the odd, seemingly successfully batchUpdate() jobs.  Thus, I resorted to batching the batchUpdate() calls into batches of 15000.  This seems to work consistently, though maybe a bit slower:

```
    //  This is the very large 2D array that is populated elsewhere
    var valueArray = [];  
    
    var maxRows = valueArray.length;
    var maxCols = valueArray[0].length;
    var batchSize = 15000;
    var lastBatchSize = 1;

    for (var currentRowCount = 1; currentRowCount <= maxRows; ++currentRowCount) {
      if( currentRowCount % batchSize == 0
         || currentRowCount == maxRows
        )
      {

        Logger.log("get new valuesToSet");
        valuesToSet = valueArray.slice(lastBatchSize - 1, currentRowCount -1);
        
        
        var data = [
          {
            range: (ss.getSheetName() + "!A" + lastBatchSize + ":AQ" + (lastBatchSize + valuesToSet.length))
            ,values: valuesToSet
          }
        ];
        
        const resource = {
          valueInputOption: "RAW"
          ,data: data
        };
        
        
        Logger.log("request       = " + JSON.stringify(resource).slice(1, 100)
          + "\n" + "valuesToSet.length           = " + valuesToSet.length
        );
        
        
        try {

          var checkValues = null;
          var continueToNextBatch = false;
          for (var i = 1; i <= 3; ++i) {
            Logger.log("try # = " + i
              + "\n" + " continueToNextBatch = " + continueToNextBatch
              + "\n" + " make the batchUpdate() request, then sleep for 5 seconds, then check if there are values in the target range."
              + "\n" + " if no values, then wait 5 seconds, check again."
              + "\n" + " if still not values after 3 tries, then resubmit the batchUpdate() requestion and recheck values"
              + "\n" + "range to check           = " + "A" + lastBatchSize + ":AQ" + lastBatchSize
            );
            
            Logger.log(" Sheets.Spreadsheets.Values.batchUpdate(params, batchUpdateValuesRequestBody)    ");
            var response = Sheets.Spreadsheets.Values.batchUpdate(resource, spreadsheetId);
            Logger.log("response  = " + response.toString());
          
            /// loop and check for data in newly written range
            for (var checks = 1; checks <= 3; ++checks) {
              Utilities.sleep(5000);
              var checkValues = ss.getRange(("A" + lastBatchSize + ":AQ" + lastBatchSize)).getValues();
              Logger.log("new cell populated - checks # = " + checks
                + "\n" + "range to check      = " + "A" + lastBatchSize + ":AQ" + lastBatchSize
                + "\n" + "checkValues.length  = " +  checkValues.length
                + "\n" + "checkValues         = " + checkValues
              );
              if(checkValues.length > 1)
              {
                Logger.log("checkValues.length > 1, so continue to next batch"
                  + "\n" + "range to check           = " + "A" + lastBatchSize + ":AQ" + lastBatchSize
                  + "\n" + "checkValues.length  = " +  checkValues.length
                  + "\n" + "checkValues         = " + checkValues
                );
                continueToNextBatch = true;
                continue;
              }
              else
              {
                Logger.log("checkValues.length is still not > 1, so  try the request again"
                  + "\n" + "range to check           = " + "A" + lastBatchSize + ":AQ" + lastBatchSize
               );
              }
            }
            
            if(continueToNextBatch)
            {
              continue;
            }
          }
          
        }
        catch (e) {
          console.error("range.setValues(valuesToSet) -  yielded an error: " + e
               + "\n" + "valuesToSet       = " + valuesToSet.length
               + "\n" + "maxRows           = " + maxRows
               + "\n" + "maxCols           = " + maxCols
               + "\n" + "currentRowCount   = " + currentRowCount
               + "\n" + "current range row start (lastBatchSize)    = " + lastBatchSize
               + "\n" + "current range row end   (j - lastBatchSize) = " + (currentRowCount - lastBatchSize)
          );
        }

        lastBatchSize = currentRowCount;
       }
    }
```

Comment: Glad you found a workaround - could we still see the original code (some extra info mentioned in question comments) - this way someone may be able to provide a solution?

Comment: @OlegValter - i'm not sure what else is needed to describe this problem?  The "ss" variable is just the active Spreadsheet.  The response in the initial description shows the size of the array, and as best I can tell, the logic for populating the array is irrelevant?

Comment: Just to see if something went a bit wrong earlier, something you might've missed accidentally, i.e. an issue with how `valueArray` populated, for example. I have as much idea about what is causing your problem as you (as from what I gathered this is likely not to be a limitations problem)